# Terraform: Convert list of object to list of single element from object

Tags: terraform

I have a list of objects from a variable in terraform

```
variable "persons" {
  type = list(object({
    name = string,
    phonenumber = string,
    tshirtSize = string
  }))
    description = "List of person"
}
```

Now I want a list of the person's names so I can use it to define an AWS Resource

How can I convert this object list to a list of names
`["bob", "amy", "jane"]`

I'm on terraform 0.12.24, though can upgrade if needed

Answer (score 30, accepted):

**Updated Answer**:
Use the splat expression

```
var.persons[*].name
```

https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/expressions/splat

**Original Answer:**
I was able to do this in locals file

```
locals {
  names = [
    for person in var.persons:
    person.name
  ]
}
```

For additional reading
SEE: https://www.hashicorp.com/blog/hashicorp-terraform-0-12-preview-for-and-for-each/

Comment: That is a fine answer! You might also be interested in the [splat expression](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/expressions.html#splat-expressions) shorthand: `var.persons[*].name`. That expressions page is the best reference for Terraform language; the 0.12 announcement blog posts are old and not updated.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it and if you want to make it an answer I'll accept it. :)

Comment: Thanks for that surprisingly simple solution! I was already seeing me again in nested for loop hell xD